# jquery-sortable unstable child sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use the jquery-sortable, basically for nesting and ordering items.
At the first level and the first item child, it works well for the nesting and sorting. However the childs of the second and subsequent items cant be sorted probably.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <ul class="list-group sortable">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      First
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          First Child 1
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          First Child 2
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          First Child 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      Second
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Second Child 1
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Second Child 2
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Second Child 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      Third
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Third Child 1
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Third Child 2
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Third Child 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>


$(function() {
  $("ul.sortable").sortable({
    group: 'List'
  });
});
```

Here's the fiddle to demonstate this https://jsfiddle.net/2p17v6xs/

I'm not sure what is it that I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: I guess inner one works too. drag from top to bottom.

Comment: I was playing around with the fiddle a bit...looks like if you move the nested `<ul>`s out from their parent `<li>`, they will work (while keeping them still within their original parent `<ul>`). You lose the margins/indentations via the native HTML styling though. Right now you've got a parent `<ul>` with child `<li>` items, and `<ul>`'s inside of those child `<li>` items. If you just move the `<ul>` as a direct child of the parent `<ul>` (not wrapped in a `<li>`) the sorting will work...could always wrap it in a span tag or do some custom styling to get the appearance you need...

Comment: Actually..my above comment is not the best solution either..its a little sketchy behavior...what about just creating separate stand alone `<ul>` lists for each, and use classes/CSS to give them their desired appearance. It does seem like the nested lists don't behave as they should--your write up and code all looks implemented properly..

Comment: It is working without bootstrap..

Comment: The issue seems to be with parents `<li>` which have a `position:relative`

Comment: thank you for the insight everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with your fiddle, I noticed it is working without bootstrap: `.list-group-item` has as a style `position:relative`, and it seems as parents of nested container can not contains `position: relative`: it probably mess with the position calculation, the lib seems miss calculating container's position which have "position:relative". It is probably an issue with the lib itself. To solve it, you can:

- Solve the lib
- Add a hack to bootstrap:

Html:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <ul class="list-group sortable">
    <li class="list-group-item no-position">
      First
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          First Child 1
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          First Child 2
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          First Child 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item no-position">
      Second
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Second Child 1
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Second Child 2
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Second Child 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item no-position">
      Third
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Third Child 1
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Third Child 2
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Third Child 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
    .no-position:not(.dragged) {
      position: initial;
    }
```

I can not think of another way.

Comment: Thank you, so I guess the issue itself lies in the bootstrap list-group instead of the plugin itself, I'll just use my own styling for this then.

Comment: Thats right, having `position:relative` on each element is weird